# @ReplaceSubstring doesn't display value as expected

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula, domino-designer-eclipse

I have this formula in one of the columns in my view in Lotus notes database. However, it does not change the value of the field "EmployeeName" in the view and still displays the original name.

Example: 
**Original** **value**: `Franco Martínez, José Ramó`
**Expected** **output**: `Franco Martinez, Jose Ramo`

```
value1:="i";
value2:="e";
value3:="o";

optionList := value1:value2:value3;
aliasList := "í":"é":"ó";


@ReplaceSubstring(@Text(EmployeeName); aliasList; optionList)
```

Comment: If that's the entire formula, it looks correct to me. Did you make the change in a template, or directly in the live database? How did you test it? Were you working in a local replica or in a replica on a server? Are you sure that the view was refreshed?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz i made the update to the template and then refreshed the changes on the production copy i then refreshed the view and it did not work ? I tried the same on my local copy but it would still show me the same data ? In past i had a weired experience were it took like about 3-4 hours or even sometime a day to show the changes ? not everytime though ? any idea what should i do

Comment: In the document properties dialog, when you look at the document containing "Franco Martínez, José Ramó", is the EmployeeName field an ordinary text item? Or is it marked as RFC822 Text?  (I can't really see a reason why that would make a difference to @ReplaceSubstring, but honestly it's the only thing I can think to check.)

Comment: Field Name: EmployeeName
Data Type: Text List
Data Length: 31 bytes
Seq Num: 35
Dup Item ID: 0
Field Flags: SUMMARY 
"Franco Martínez, José Ramón"
this is what it says ? its really weird why the above formula would not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the formula is absolutely correct, the issue has to be somewhere else.
You already checked, that the field is summary, so this cannot be the issue.

Please check the programmatic name of the column (last tab in the properties): 
Does it happen to match another column in the same view or is it probably "EmployeeName"? Then just remove the name, it will be repopulated by a new unique name.

Explanation:
Duplicate programmatic names mean, that both columns show the same value, and the formula of the second columnn is never executed. If there is a Fieldname in the name of the column, then it will always show the value of that field, no matter what the formula sais.

Another explanation could be that "í" <> "í"... Probably one of them is the representation of another Unicode- Character and just happens to "look" like the other one... You can check this using a button or agent that just @Prompts the value after replacesubstring, or copy the content of the field into a Hex- Editor...

You could also try the @Ascii() - @Function to convert to ascii without having to replace characters.

Comment: I thought about the "í" <> "í", but in a formula you are not dealing with Unicode. You are dealing with LMBCS. Unicode definitely allows composites of multiple code points (base code point + diacritic code point) characters that are equivalent to precomposed single code points, but I don't think LMBCS allows that. Not sure, though.

Comment: So basically the code i posted above plus i used the method Torsten suggested @Ascii(@Text(EmployeeName) both worked fine the problem was like Torsten mentioned with the programmatic name i tried to change the programmatic name and they both worked fine. That particular view has almost 250 fields due to which it was difficult to understand if there was a duplicate. I still don't know if there is a duplicate but i am assuming there is one based on Torsten explanation.